# IIS & XAMPP Conflict, Ports Already Changed

Tags: wordpress, iis, xampp, virtualhost

I have IIS enabled (fresh "install") and a port configured XAMPP install with a fresh Wordpress build.

**httpd.conf (changes):**

```
Listen 8080
ServerName localhost:8080
```

**httpd-ssl.conf (changes):**

```
Listen 4433
<VirtualHost _default_:4433>
ServerName www.example.com:4433
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf (changes):**

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/foobar"
    ServerName foo.bar
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/foobar">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts (changes):**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       foo.bar
```

**Tests:**

- http://localhost/

  - IIS Root (expected)
- http://localhost:8080/[dashboard]

  - XAMPP Root (expected)
- http://localhost:8080/foobar

  - resolves to http://localhost/foobar, displays IIS error page (incorrect, should show the Wordpress install)
- http://foo.bar

  - displays IIS root (incorrect, should show Wordpress install)
- http://foo.bar:8080

  - resolves to http://foo.bar (same result as above)

Honestly, at this point I have no idea what I have setup that is incorrect. I've spent all day reading forums and SO, and I'm not making any headway. Help? Am I making incorrect assumptions on behavior or do I have a mistake in my setup?

Comment: I assume you closed the VirtualHost tag in httpd-ssl.conf (changes):

Comment: If your XAMPP comes with Apache 2.4 `NameVirtualHost *:8080` is not longer allowed.

Comment: When you installed WordPress what url did you use when you ran the install. It matters. If you installed it using `localhost/foobar` that would explain the url swap from `http://foo.bar` and `http://localhost:8080/foobar` to the IIS server.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, the VirtualHost tag is closed, only the port got updated. I did notice the error in the log about the NameVirtualHost *:8080 being deprecated, but removing it didn't seem to have any effect. As for the site url, I'm using `define('WP_HOME', 'http://foo.bar');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://foo.bar');` in the wp-config.

Comment: Have you also checked the WP database, it holds the url that was used when the install was run, see [WP Docs Changing The Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yup, the database has been made to match and hasn't had any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want both services running at the same time, that you'll mostly be working with XAMPP. This is my solution:

I'm not a fan of typing in port 8080 whenever I want to be working with XAMPP. So I just changed the post number of IIS to 82.

1. Start IIS (7) On the left go to `YOUR MACHINE` > `Sites` > `Default Web Site`
2. Then on the right click on `bindings` then a window pops up
3. Click on the first row and edit the port number to anyting but 80 (because 80 is the default port if you don't type in anything in
   your browser)
4. Reset all the settings of httpd.conf, httpd-ssl.conf
5. Then open httpd-vhosts.conf and put this:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\foobar
>    ServerName foo.bar
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

6. Restart your computer (httpd-vhosts.conf doesn't take effect without)

The file `hosts` is fine as it is.